# need to get data from web service using Angular 4 service

Tags: angular, web-services, typescript, data-binding, angular-services

I created a service to help me pull details from a web service by sending a specific ID to the back-end then fetching data regarding the selected ID,
I created a function to call the service, now i want just to know what is missing in my code.

My service:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpErrorResponse, HttpParams } from 
'@angular/common/http';
import { environment } from '../../environment/environment'
import { SchoolsModel } from '../models/school-model';

@Injectable()
export class GradesService {
constructor(public http: HttpClient) {
}

public getSchoolGrades(schoolId: number) {
const apiUrl: string = environment.apiBaseUrl + 
'/api/en/admin/grades/division';
let promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  return this.http.get(apiUrl, { params: new 
HttpParams().set("school_id", schoolId.toString()) })
    .subscribe(respose => {
      console.log(respose.data);
      return resolve(respose.data);
    }, (err: HttpErrorResponse) => {
      return reject(err);
    });
});
return promise;

}

}
```

My component TS:

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewEncapsulation } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute, ParamMap } from '@angular/router';
import { AuthService } from '../common-services/auth/auth.service';
import { UserService } from '../common-services/user.service';
import { Title } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { SchoolsModel } from '../models/school-model';
import { SchoolsService } from '../business-services/schools.service';
import { GradesService } from '../business-services/grades.service';

declare const $;
@Component({
selector: 'app-divisions',
 templateUrl: './divisions.component.html',
styleUrls: ['./divisions.component.css'],
encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.Emulated
})
export class DivisionsComponent implements OnInit {

  public divisionList: SchoolsModel;

constructor(
private schoolService: SchoolsService,
private gradesService: GradesService,
private titleService: Title,
private authService: AuthService,
private route: ActivatedRoute
) {}

ngOnInit(): void {

         this.getSchoolGrades();

}

private getSchoolGrades(schoolId: number) {
this.gradesService.getSchoolGrades(schoolId)
  .then((division: SchoolsModel) => {
   // debugger;
    this.divisionList = division;
  }).catch(err => {
    console.error("Error occured :", err)
  })
}


}
```

My component HTML

```
<div>
<button name="American Primary" 
class="choose-list arrow-onclick1" data-toggle="collapse" data-
target="#list1">
{{divisionList.name}}<i class="fa fa-arrow-right pull-
right arrow-down-onclick1" aria-hidden="true" style="margin-top: 
12px"></i>
</button>
<a routerLink="/editaisdivision" 
style="text-decoration: none;"><span class="fa fa-pencil pen-pen-pen" 
aria-hidden="true" style="margin-left: 10px; color: #171b5e;"></span>
</a>
</div>
```

Schools Model:

```
export class SchoolsModel{
id:number;
name:string;
logo:string;
vision:string;
mission:string;
address:string;
latitude:number;
longitude:number;
district_id:number;
created_at:Date;
updated_at:Date;
}
```

Environment:

```
export const environment = {
apiBaseUrl: 'https://crm.easyschools.org'
 }
```

I guess this is everything you might need to tell me why component is not catching the right data from the web service and displaying it on the screen.

I'm trying to be as specific as i can so if something is not clear just tell me.

Comment: Did you find answer for above approach?

Comment: yes, check the accepted answer, and if you need further assistance, reply me and i will help if i can.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using promises is not really the optimal solution when you have such a powerful instrument as RxJs, especially since it's what Angular uses to handle http requests. Try to rewrite your service as follows:

```
public getSchoolGrades(schoolId: number) {
    const apiUrl: string = environment.apiBaseUrl + 
'/api/en/admin/grades/division';
    return this.http.get(apiUrl, { params: new HttpParams().set("school_id", schoolId.toString()) });
}
```

Then in your component:

```
ngOnInit(): void { 
    this.getSchoolGrades(123);
}

private getSchoolGrades(schoolId: number) {
    this.gradesService.getSchoolGrades(schoolId)
        .catch(err => {
            console.error("Error occured :", err)
        })
        .subscribe((division: SchoolsModel) => {
            this.divisionList = division;
        });
}
```

Comment: not working, when i write {{divisionList.name}} for ex i get in the console that property name is not defined

Comment: are you receiving any data in subscribe? is the request working?

Comment: a debug context, i made a shareable project on stackblitz, can you take a quick look?

Comment: sure, where is the link?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/165032/discussion-between-boris-lobanov-and-mohamed-wahshey).

Comment: project is private

Answer (score 0):

Your method signature is this

`getSchoolGrades(schoolId: number)`

But in ngOnInit you are calling the method without passing a schoolId

```
this.getSchoolGrades();
```

Comment: I need the function to read the selected school id not to give it a static id, how do i do that?

Comment: You could attach a (click) event to the item displayed, and handle the logic inside that method, taking the id of the selected item. Calling `getSchoolGrades` inside ngOnInit wihout knowing what school the user selected doesn't make sense @MohamedWahshey

Comment: i still get an eroor when i define the school id, says that property not defined on the console

Answer (score 0):

**This is the simple way to call a webservice and get result**

```
let token="Bearer"+" "+tokenUser;
    var headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('Authorization',token);
    headers.append('Content-Type','application/json');
    let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
    this.spinnerService.show();
    this.http.get('https://www.000webhost.com/sample/rest_api/api/all-user-details',options)
    .subscribe((res)=> {
         this.spinnerService.hide();            
         this.userdetails=res.json();

         console.log(this.userdetails);  

      }
        ,(err) => {
        this.spinnerService.hide();
        console.log("Error occured");
      });         
  }



  <tbody>
       <tr *ngFor = "let user of userdetails; let i=index">                   
       <td align="left" valign="middle">{{i+1}}</td>

       <td align="left" valign="middle">{{user.IPADDRESS}}</td> 
       <td align="left" valign="middle">{{user.INSERT}}</td>     
       <td align="left" valign="middle">{{user.UPDATE}}</td>     
      </tr> 
</tbody>
```